# Profile a blender file to optimize render speed and quality

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, optimization

I know the gaming world has tools to optimize performance for their target devices... Do we have something like that in the Blender realm?

I would love to understand my blend files better with an eye toward wringing as much out of them as possible at render without breaking the bank or melting a CPU -- how to stay under GPU memory, where and how mesh densities are killing times, how and where trade-offs exist between skin sizes and render speeds.... Is anything like this available?

I suspect this question also entails stuff I do not know to ask or look for -- when skin sizes could be higher/lower in a scene, using LoD more effectively than I do... and more, as I have only an experience-based sense for when adding or subtracting "weight" helps... and that's not really scientific.

We (try to) do high-realism scenes with natural environmental components -- lighting, volumetrics, particles, water... and optimizing for hardware rendering is proving to be an important issue, especially as me move to 4K stuff.

[image]

I know (some) tricks to optimize scene weights: We use scrims, layer passes, post processing of volumetrics and more... but if I could analyze a live file to see where render demands are spiking, that would be cool. So this is less a question about render optimizing approaches in general and more about understanding the guts of render demands on a per-file basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cycles Roadmap](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Source/Render/Cycles/Roadmap) mentions the following goal:

> **Statistics**: for power users to investigate why rendering performance is slow, why memory usage is high, which objects or materials to optimize, etc. This would be a log generated that could be shown in Blender or as a HTML report, and possibly also debugging AOVs.

However, this goal currently (December 2016) is not scheduled to happen soon, it is in the

> things we think are very important, but that no one at the meeting planned to work on within a specific time frame.

category.

Comment: I have learned from the Foundation that the Cycles roadmap link you provided may not accurately reflect their current plans and hopes. As I learn more, I will note it here....

Comment: @rcgauer Or you could reach even more people by updating the Cycles roadmap document itself, it is a wiki after all...

Comment: Discussed with Ton via email --  that road map seems not to be the current one....

Comment: I understood that. That's why is should be updated - in order to *become* the current one.